# How to bring a transformer's secondary impedance to the primary side with k < 1?

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, impedance, tesla-coil

I know that when I have a transformer with a coupling coefficient of 1, I can use the formula `Z' = Z × (N₁ / N₂)²`. How could I calculate this impedance with a coupling coefficient of 0.2? Also, is the impedance of the secondary coil part of `Z`?

I'm not sure if that's important, but my exact application is a Tesla coil. Air-cored, 4 MHz, varying load. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the primary excitation current and thus must be greater than 10% of max load, then no loss in voltage. So loss from M depends on L,  if high Z then huge loss

Comment: I actually don't want to reduch the loss in voltage. I'm driving the primary coil with a class e amplifier, for which I have to know the exact load impadence to design it correctly.

Comment: What is the impedance of the arc??.  Use a dual step up transformer with a spark plug and cap intermediate and low L 2nd stepup to get the fastest dI/dt

Comment: Do you know L and n options..? Why 4MHz?

Comment: Do you have a 5kVA transformer for the 1st stage?  https://tinyurl.com/ydn9a6fx. I doubt it.

Comment: I simulated my setup, so I know all important values. I chose 4 MHz, since it's a challenge to do and produces silent sparks. I have no high-voltage equipment, so the only thing I can do is simulate and calculate. And since the duration of the spark is so low, I'll just assume, there is none.

Comment: Did you know all arcs break the speed of sound which is why you hear it start?

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate the magnetization inductance because otherwise, your question is flawed (as it imposes a belief that transformer impedance is governed purely by the load on the secondary and the turns ratio).

When you factor in the magnetization impedance you get a correct answer for k = 1 by making the reflected load impedance in parallel with this inductance.

When k is less than 1, you have leakage inductance (basically 1-k multiplied by the magnetization inductance) and, it is in series with the transformer primary and acts only on its own hence, it represents an impedance you have to add to the reflected impedance from the secondary. And, of course you have a reduced magnetization inductance due to k being less than one so, you also still have the same old parallel path to the reflected impedance and those two impedances are in series with the leakage inductance.